# Selecting child element of a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select a child element of a parent element and I can't do it, because every time I use  `.find` or `.children` method of jQuery, it selects the parent element that has it, not the child element itself. I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul class="parent element">
    <li class="child1 red"></li>
    <li class="child2"></li>
    <li class="child3"></li>
    <li class="child4"></li>
    <li class="child5"></li>
    <li class="child6"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to select `li` that has `red` class from `ul` parent element. I tried:

```
$("ul").find("li.red");
```

but it selects the `ul` element itself, not the first `li` element. How can I select the first element?

*(first element is symbolic, assume that we don't know which order the `li` elements are in)*

Comment: Pretty sure that won't select the ul element itself. Something else is wrong with your code that is not reflected in what is given here.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Why not plain js? I.e to get a _list_ of all elements matching the criteria: `document.querySelectorAll('ul li.red');`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fjZ3/ - Just for your own verification, here is a working example of what you want to do. (if you remove the JavaScript, the background is red. Otherwise, it's blue.)

Comment: `but it selects the ul element` Then you're not telling us everything.  What you have above *will not* select the ul.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul > li.red")
```

This will select the child element of your `<ul>` with the class `red`.

Comment: "This will select the child element of your <ul> with the class red". So would the code he provided.

Comment: This is same like find. As per jquery documentation find selects the element fast compare to the above method

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct selection already,

`$("ul").find("li.red")`

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbWB2/)

Comment: "It works" isn't an answer.

Comment: What? sure it is. I'm demonstrating that the problem is not with the selection as OP suggested

Comment: No it isn't. "Your code works" or "I can't reproduce the problem" are useful statements, but they should be comments, not answers.

Comment: I see, then no one should have posted any answers.

Comment: I did not know that was the way of doing things, thanks for cluing me in